# Efficiently parsing time formatting in pandas/python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame as below

```
+-----------+------+--------------+
| invoiceNo | time | invoiceValue |
+-----------+------+--------------+
|     A     |   6  |       2      |
+-----------+------+--------------+
|     B     |  12  |       3      |
+-----------+------+--------------+
|     C     |  356 |       5      |
+-----------+------+--------------+
|     D     | 2145 |       6      |
+-----------+------+--------------+

df = pd.DataFrame({'invoiceNo':['A','B','C','D'],
             'time':[6,12,356,2145],
             'invoiceValue':[2,3,5,6] })
```

my task is to extract the corresponding `hour` from the `time` value.

However, the issue is, ideally the `time` column should show `4` digits. but, due to number formatting, it strips off the leading zeros. hence, `6` here means `0006` which is `00 hour` & `06 minutes`

in-order to accomplish this, I've written the below code and it works perfectly well.

```
df['adj-time'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: '{0:0>4}'.format(x))
df['adj-time'] = df['adj-time'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x,format= '%H%M'))
df['hour'] = df['adj-time'].apply(lambda x: x.hour)
df.drop('adj-time',axis=1, inplace=True)
```

below is my desired output

```
+-----------+------+--------------+------+
| invoiceNo | time | invoiceValue | hour |
+-----------+------+--------------+------+
|     A     |   6  |       2      |   0  |
+-----------+------+--------------+------+
|     B     |  12  |       3      |   0  |
+-----------+------+--------------+------+
|     C     |  356 |       5      |   3  |
+-----------+------+--------------+------+
|     D     | 2145 |       6      |  21  |
+-----------+------+--------------+------+
```

However, my question is, the above code is `very very slow` and `time consuming` when it comes to large data set.

how can I make it more efficient in terms of performance/speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use string manipulation to extract the hours. `zfill` up to 4 characters (6 if you have seconds too) and then slice the first 2 to get the hours ([2:4] for the minutes and [4:6] for seconds). Use `pd.to_numeric` to get a numeric dtype.

```
df['hour'] = pd.to_numeric(df['time'].astype(str).str.zfill(4).str[0:2])
df['minutes'] = pd.to_numeric(df['time'].astype(str).str.zfill(4).str[2:4])

  invoiceNo  time  invoiceValue  hour  minutes
0         A     6             2     0        6
1         B    12             3     0       12
2         C   356             5     3       56
3         D  2145             6    21       45
```

---

In case you are interested in converting your `'time'` to a `timedelta64[ns]` dtype you can use the flexible parsing of `pd.to_datetime`. Because year/month/day are missing it defaults to 1900-01-01, which we subtract off.

```
df['new_time'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['time'].astype(str).str.zfill(4), format='%H%M')
                  - pd.to_datetime('1900-01-01'))

  invoiceNo  time  invoiceValue  hour  minutes        new_time
0         A     6             2     0        6 0 days 00:06:00
1         B    12             3     0       12 0 days 00:12:00
2         C   356             5     3       56 0 days 03:56:00
3         D  2145             6    21       45 0 days 21:45:00
```

Comment: Thank you. I applied the above solution to the actual dataset. The speed has greatly improved. Awesome.

Answer (score 1):

if you time is integer then:

```
hour = int(time/100)
```

if it is string:

```
hour = int(int(time)/100)
```

Comment: I like your thought process and the simple solution. the reason why I prefer time formatting is that, I want to make my code future proof. meaning, if I want to extract the minutes in future analysis. I should be able to do it easily. I Upvoted your answer. it was great out of the box thinking..

Answer (score 1):

- Also using `zfill`
- Set `'time'` as a string, convert to a datetime and extract the hour component.

```py
df['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df.time.astype('str').str.zfill(4), format='%H%M').dt.hour

# display(df)
  invoiceNo  time  invoiceValue  hour
0         A     6             2     0
1         B    12             3     0
2         C   356             5     3
3         D  2145             6    21
```

### read from csv

- Set the type of the `'time'` column when reading the data in, and then `.astype('str')` is not required.

```py
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', dtype={'time': str})
df['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df.time.str.zfill(4), format='%H%M').dt.hour
```

### `timeit` tests

```py
# 2M rows of data
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':[6,12,356,2145]})
dft = pd.concat([df] * 500000).reset_index(drop=True)

%%timeit
pd.to_datetime(dft.time.astype('str').str.zfill(4), format='%H%M').dt.hour
[out]:
1.51 s ± 23.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
pd.to_numeric(dft.time.astype(str).str.zfill(4).str[0:2])
[out]:
2.6 s ± 41.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Awesome. your answer also drastically improved the calculation speed. hence, Upvoted. I already accepted @ALollz answer. Thank you.!

Comment: got it. I applied both the solutions to a subset of my dataset. picked `2.1Mn rows ` and `42 columns `. these columns consists of varying `dtypes`. your solution is 2 seconds faster.